# Torsion module and its socle

Tags: modules, abelian-groups, socle

A torsion abelian group has nonzero socle and is an essential extension of it. Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $M$ is a unital, torsion $R$-module with nonzero socle, is $M$ an essential extension of its socle?

Comment: Is R an integral domain?  Otherwise, I think for an arbitrary torsion theory, the answer is no.

Comment: @Jack: $R$ could be an integral domain, but I do not want to restrict to that case. In general, I would want to say that $m$ is a torsion element if $rm=0$ for some regular element $r$ in $R$. I don't want to get into an arbitrary torsion theory because I don't understand them all that well yet.

Comment: cool. That removes my silly examples ("m is torsion if it is torsion free or annihilated by a power of 2. then Z+Z/2Z has nonzero socle, is torsion, and its socle is not essential").  I'll think about this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

**Example:** Let $R=k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring in two variables, and let $$M=R/yR \oplus R/(x,y)R = M_1 \oplus M_2.$$  Then *y* acts as 0 on *M*, but *y* is a regular element on *R*, so *M* is not only torsion but "bounded".  *M* has socle $M_2$, but $M_1 \cap M_2 = 0$, so the socle $M_2$ is not essential.

Verifying the example is easier if you imagine *M* as an $S=k[x]$ module, then $M_1 \cong S$ obviously has zero socle as an *S*-module, and thus as an *R*-module. $M_2 \cong k$ is simple, so its own socle.

Here is my thought process (removing dead-ends on singular modules).  Basically reduce to injectives, then reduce to R/P, and check the condition on R/P.  Dim 2 rings are mostly fine, especially ones with lots of primes.

**Lemma 1:** An essential extension of a torsion-module is torsion.

**Lemma 2:** Every module has a maximal essential extension, namely its injective envelope.

**Lemma 3:** Over a commutative noetherian ring, every injective module is a direct sum of injective envelopes of $R/P$ where *P* is a prime ideal of *R*.

**Lemma 4:** A cyclic module $R/I$ is torsion if and only if *I* contains a regular element.

**Lemma 5:** A cyclic module $R/I$ has a non-essential socle if *I* is the intersection of infinitely many prime ideals.

**Lemma 6:** What we really need is a nonzero non-maximal prime ideal in a noetherian domain.

Comment: Hopefully it is also clear this is the same as my earlier example.  Take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $y=2$, then *M* in my answer is suspiciously identical to *M* in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. This is exactly the kind of example I was hoping for but could not construct myself. The lemmas will help with a general result I am trying to establish.